Checkbox is not selecting paginated data in JavaScript
I have a C# MVC project , in which I am trying to select all the checkbox using header checkbox in table. but on selection it only selects first page data not all paginated data.
I am using AJAX for capturing selected data.
my table code is below:
<div class="table-container">
<table class="table" id="deviceTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"></th>
<th>Device Serial</th>
<th>Device Name</th>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>User Email</th>
                @* <th>Migration Not Started</th>
<th>Migration In Progress</th>
<th>Migration Completed</th>
<th>Migration Failed</th> *@
 
                <th>Last Updated Time</th>
<th>Wave/Ring Number</th>
<th>Overall Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="deviceTableBody">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="row-checkbox" data-id="@item.DeviceSerial"></td>
<td>@item.DeviceSerial</td>
<td>@item.DeviceName</td>
<td>@item.UserName</td>
<td>@item.UserEmail</td>
                    @* <td>@(item.MigrationNotStarted ? "Not Started" : "Started")</td>
<td>@(item.MigrationInProgress ? "In Progress" : "Not In Progress")</td>
<td>@(item.MigrationCompleted ? "Completed" : "Not Completed")</td>
<td>@(item.MigrationFailed ? "Failed" : "Not Failed")</td> *@
 
                    <td>@item.LastUpdatedTime</td>
<td>@item.WaveNumber</td>
<td class="overall-status">
                        @if (item.OverallStatus == "In Progress")
                        {
<span class="circle blue" data-status="In Progress" id="circle-@item.DeviceSerial"></span>
                        }
                        else if (item.OverallStatus == "Failed")
                        {
<span class="circle red" data-status="Failed" id="circle-@item.DeviceSerial"></span>
                        }
                        else if (item.OverallStatus == "Completed")
                        {
<span class="circle green" data-status="Completed" id="circle-@item.DeviceSerial"></span>
                        }
                        else if (item.OverallStatus == "Not Started")
                        {
<span class="circle yellow" data-status="Not Started" id="circle-@item.DeviceSerial"></span>
                        }
                        else if (item.OverallStatus == "Completed(Manually)")
                        {
<span class="circle greenyellow" data-status="Completed(Manually)" id="circle-@item.DeviceSerial"></span>
                        }
                        @item.OverallStatus
</td>
</tr>
            }
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

also my AJAX is below:
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handle select all checkbox
    $('#selectAll').click(function () {
        $('.row-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
 
    // Handle individual row checkbox change
    $('.row-checkbox').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $('#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
 
    // Handle Mark as Completed button click
    $('#markAsCompleted').click(function () {
        var selectedIds = [];
        $('.row-checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            selectedIds.push($(this).data('id'));
        });
 
        console.log(selectedIds);
 
        var serializedData = JSON.stringify(selectedIds); // Convert data to JSON string as an array
        console.log("serializedData", serializedData);
 
        if (selectedIds.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/MarkAsCompleted',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: serializedData,
                success: function (response) {
                    // Update the UI to reflect the changes
                    selectedIds.forEach(function (id) {
                        var row = $('#circle-' + id).closest('tr');
                        row.find('.overall-status').html('<span class="circle greenyellow" data-status="Completed(Manually)"></span>Completed(Manually)');
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Error updating status: ", error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please select at least one row to mark as completed.');
        }
    });
});

when I console log below JavaScript code:
// Handle select all checkbox
    $('#selectAll').click(function () {
        $('.row-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    })

it does not capture all the selected values.
I am new to this , any help will be thankful.

You mention pagination but I don't see any code related to that in your sample. Are you loading a new set of records on a click or something of the sort?

Could you please share few more relevant data related to your pagination and how you are loading the table?

I have tried to reproduce your scenario and the issue you're facing is related to the fact that only the checkboxes present in the current DOM are being affected by your JavaScript code. When you paginate, only the visible rows are in the DOM, so your $('#selectAll').click(function () { $('.row-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked); }) only affects these rows.

@MdFaridUddinKiron, can you share the changes for multipage not for  the visible rows are in the  current DOM.
